# JSONObject[str] is not a JSONObject while parsing JSON

Tags: java, json

I am trying to deserialize (parse) this JSON: `{"test": "TEST2"}`

I am new to Java, so I've searched a lot on Google and I finally found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203/8524395

So, I am trying to deserialize my JSON like that:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"test\": \"TEST2\"}");
String testValue = obj.getJSONObject("test").toString();
```

But I am getting the error: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"test\": \"TEST2\"}");
        String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("test").toString();`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should get a string not another object:

```
String testValue = obj.getString("test");
```

In other word, `test` is a key that maps to a string of value `TEST2`.